# Updating the UI thread works incorrectly in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I Want to update UI fields after some calculations. But it Runs wrong.

```
 SolvePuzzle sp = new SolvePuzzle(table);
 solved_puzzle = sp.Solve();
```

after calculating `Solve()` Function, its results that saved in `solved_puzzle` should be shown on app UI.
to set that values I  use `set_values()` function:

```
set_values(solved_puzzle);
```

on `set_values()` function I'll set UI Elements:

```
private void set_values(int[][] solved_puzzle1) {
    final int[][] solved_puzzle = solved_puzzle1;

    System.out.print(solved_puzzle1[0][0]);


    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            t1.setText(String.valueOf(solved_puzzle[0][0]));
        }
}
```

now `System.out.print(solved_puzzle1[0][0]);` outputs for example `1` but t1 value is `0`.

Do you know what should I do?

Comment: I would recommend adding more debugging statements, and trying to use more different names so you can see what's going on. It's very hard to tell what's wrong from just this example.

Comment: This is hard to diagnose without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)